# Trying to restore data, usb drive not properly detected?

Tags: linux, usb, data-recovery

I am trying to recover files from a usb drive with a corrupted filesystem, thus far I have had no luck. When hooking it up to a machine with Ubuntu I get the following information:

**Syslog**

```
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3298.022291] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3298.116517] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5200
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3298.116523] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3298.116526] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Flash Drive
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3298.116528] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Philips
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3298.116530] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 070831592E1C2876
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3298.116918] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3298.117266] scsi12 : usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
 - OptiPlex-7010 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
 - OptiPlex-7010 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 14 was not an MTP device
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3299.115739] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Philips  USB Flash Drive  PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3299.116140] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3299.116915] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] 30283008 512-byte logical blocks: (15.5 GB/14.4 GiB)
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3299.117689] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3299.117694] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3299.118421] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3299.137329]  sdb: unknown partition table
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3299.140092] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3329.448823] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
 - OptiPlex-7010 kernel: [ 3344.527989] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

**mesg | grep USB**:

```
 - [    2.224837] usb-storage 3-1.1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 - [    2.224936] scsi6 : usb-storage 3-1.1.1:1.0
 - [    2.224996] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
 - [   87.256995] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
 - [   87.274456] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5200
 - [   87.274461] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 - [   87.274464] usb 4-2: Product: USB Flash Drive
 - [   87.274466] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Philips
 - [   87.274468] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 070831592E1C2876
 - [   87.275149] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 - [   87.275334] scsi7 : usb-storage 4-2:1.0
 - [ 1084.106316] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
 - [ 1084.122984] usb 4-2: device firmware changed
 - [ 1084.123061] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
 - [ 1084.426260] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
 - [ 1084.443438] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5200
 - [ 1084.443440] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 - [ 1084.443442] usb 4-2: Product: USB DISK 53X            
 - [ 1084.443443] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Phison                  
 - [ 1084.443444] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 000000000003
 - [ 1084.444165] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 - [ 1084.444306] scsi8 : usb-storage 4-2:1.0
 - [ 1284.403097] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
 - [ 1284.404591] usb 4-2: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
 - [ 1284.404597] usb 4-2: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
 - [ 1291.258018] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
 - [ 1291.352207] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5200
 - [ 1291.352213] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 - [ 1291.352216] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Flash Drive
 - [ 1291.352218] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Philips
 - [ 1291.352220] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 070831592E1C2876
 - [ 1291.352581] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 - [ 1291.352773] scsi9 : usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
 - [ 1322.504463] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
 - [ 1337.583428] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 1352.766454] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 1352.942547] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
 - [ 1368.021532] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 1383.204543] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 1383.380617] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
 - [ 1388.403041] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 1393.525520] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 1393.701453] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
 - [ 1398.723856] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 1403.846315] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 1403.950609] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 3
 - [ 1404.022141] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
 - [ 1419.101106] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 1434.284172] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 1434.460367] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
 - [ 1449.539202] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 1464.722221] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 1464.898309] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
 - [ 1469.920845] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 1475.043166] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 1475.219114] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
 - [ 1480.241537] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 1485.363984] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 2642.131031] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2642.225170] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5200
 - [ 2642.225176] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 - [ 2642.225179] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Flash Drive
 - [ 2642.225182] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Philips
 - [ 2642.225184] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 070831592E1C2876
 - [ 2642.225571] usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 - [ 2642.225764] scsi10 : usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
 - [ 2643.367573] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2643.460763] usb 1-1.3: device firmware changed
 - [ 2643.461245] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 8
 - [ 2643.543674] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2643.637839] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5200
 - [ 2643.637845] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 - [ 2643.637848] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Flash Drive
 - [ 2643.637850] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Philips
 - [ 2643.637852] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 070831592E1C2876
 - [ 2643.638217] usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 - [ 2643.638410] scsi11 : usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
 - [ 2675.130260] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2690.209235] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 2705.392221] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 2705.568344] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2720.647328] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 2735.830344] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 2736.006427] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2741.028840] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 2746.151168] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 2746.327074] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2751.349654] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 2756.471945] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 2756.576136] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 9
 - [ 2756.647928] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2771.726911] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 2786.909932] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 2787.086008] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2802.164991] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 2817.348018] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 2817.524098] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2822.546524] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 2827.668963] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 2827.844933] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
 - [ 2832.867325] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 2837.989657] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 2984.453417] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
 - [ 2984.453423] usb 3-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
 - [ 2984.453426] usb 3-1.1.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
 - [ 3298.022291] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
 - [ 3298.116517] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5200
 - [ 3298.116523] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 - [ 3298.116526] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Flash Drive
 - [ 3298.116528] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Philips
 - [ 3298.116530] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 070831592E1C2876
 - [ 3298.116918] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 - [ 3298.117266] scsi12 : usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
 - [ 3329.448823] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
 - [ 3344.527989] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 3359.711009] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 3359.886904] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
 - [ 3374.966077] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 3390.149084] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 3390.324985] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
 - [ 3395.347546] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 3400.469846] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 3400.645797] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
 - [ 3405.668373] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 3410.790712] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 3410.895097] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 14
 - [ 3410.966629] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
 - [ 3426.045601] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 3441.228667] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 3441.404743] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
 - [ 3456.483721] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 3471.666738] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 - [ 3471.842942] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
 - [ 3476.865238] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 3481.987716] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 3482.163481] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
 - [ 3487.186053] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
 - [ 3492.308390] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
```

I have tried testdisk and some data recovery software to no avail..

I am hoping someone can help me recover the files on this usb drive, perhaps with the help of these log files. I would be eternally grateful to you if you can help me restore the data on this drive.

Answer (score 3):

USB error -110 means **power exceeded**, the computer sys could not provide enough power for the pendirve to operate. Thus the device can not provide any data i.e device descriptor thus the computer cannot identify it.

Your motherboard is probably not getting enough power, or too many devices connected.
Unplug **everything** and unplug the computer from wall for ~3 min for Mb to drain. Restart and try again with absolute minimal things plugged in.

Is anything obvious standing out? I.e. 180V Mains on a 240V Computer? Dirty USB connection pins?

Else try a friends computer with USB 3.0, I know some USB 3.0 Pendrives cannot run on USB 2.0 ports. just not enough power.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1610142

Let me know in the comments below if you need recovery help as well. =D Good luck!

Comment: Interesting, I also tried it on a Windows 7 machine where it would just show the USB drive as 0/0bytes and saying it needs formatting. It is indeed a USB 3.0 drive. I will try that solution, hopefully it will help.